# Can't select full long text document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo DB entry that has a really long text field. I need to get its entire contents but the mongo terminal truncates it. The PHP script loads the full document but i need to be able to get it from the mongo terminal so that I can look at the data while the site is not running. I'm hoping there is a command I can pass somewhere to enable it?

I see a few comments that this might be because of a null character and not because of the content length. The data is encoded with serialize if that helps. Is there still a way to view it?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How is it "truncating it"? The value or just the display of the value (if you check the value's length, is it correct)? You could probably just use a string `slice` command to print it out in chunks. `for(var i=0,l=s.length;i<l;i+=80) { print(s.slice(i,i+80)); }` assuming s contained the long string for example.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug ([SERVER-6646](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6646)) in MongoDB shell and fixed in 2.4.5.

NUL will now show up in the shell as "\u0000", along with the rest of string